# Are all omnics equal?

Tags: overwatch

Is there any noted difference between clearly self-aware omnics like Zenyata and clearly less self-aware omnics like OR15-A or the little laser shooting dogs in the Uprising PvE ?

Are they considered the same in the Universe (by Lore) or are they different ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Omnics](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Omnic) are any robot created by [Omniums](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Omnium), which are self-improving and automated robotics factories. During the [Omnic Crisis](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Omnic_Crisis) the Omniums themselves became self-aware and launched attacks at human all over the world. Most of the units produced by the Omniums were Bastion units.

The new PvE game mode [Uprising](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/King%27s_Row#Uprising) details the events in King's Row that happened seven years before the present day (so well after the Omnic Crisis). These Omnics, called the [Null Sector](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Null_Sector) consist of the offensive robots seen in the game mode. They operated out of the underground of London England.

There is another group of Omnics called the [Shambali](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Shambali) which was led by Tekhartha Mondatta. Tekhartha Zenyatta (the playable character) was also at one point a member of this group. These Omnics abandoned their pre-programmed lives to meditate in the Himalayas. After which they tried to bring peace between Omnics and Humans.

It seems Omnics can become self-aware and may choose to ignore their original programming, as what happened with the Shambali monks. You can also see this in [Bastion's](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Bastion#Story) (the playable in-game characters) background story.

Answer (score 1):

In the lore, the little omnics or the "shooting dogs" appear only on the PvE event. That type of omnics are used only for military things, like Bastion (in the event, Bastions appeared to try to kill you). On the other hand, Zenyatta is like a "human" omnics. They are just person, created to live and help people, not created to kill person, fight war, etc. Orisa (OR15-A) was created to secure people on the airports, police station, etc. But in the past, a rebellion appeared, the rebellion on the omnics, so OR15-A want to kill humans, or bastions, etc.

In short, "Zenyatta's" were created to help people and "Orisa's" for military help.

Comment: As I noted, Zenyata is clearly self-aware and is a true AI, what humanity is trying to create in real life, where the other bastions and the shooting dogs aren't self-aware and has set of commands they follow, instead of being free to do what they like like zenyata.

Comment: That's it, "Zenyattas" were created to help and the to live like humans and "Orisa's", Bastion's or "shooting dogs" were created to fight for the people or protect him for bad things, another people, fight wars, etc. They are clearlly different after Omnic's Crisis or rebellion.

Comment: For another example, the Titan Omnics you can see in the map set in Russia and in some of the comics were designed to build skyscrapers.

Comment: @SGR Those are not omnics but rather [mechs](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Volskaya_Industries) used to fight omnics during the omnic crisis